# add custom header to website hosted on IIS

Tags: powershell, iis, wmi

We have a .Net web application deployed to IIS.

Whenever we need to stop, start or recycle the application we use some powershell scripts with WMI-Object to get an ApplicationPool object to do this. All good :-)

Now we have a scenario where we have a clustered setup of frontend servers with a .Net web application being served by IIS. We have a need to have a custom header added to the responses so we can see which frontend is serving us.

We would very much like to use a powershell script and WMI-Objects to do this. But I am having a hard time finding the proper WMI-Object class to do this..

Does anyone know which class we should use to set the custom header or if it is even possible with WMI-Object?

Comment: Looks like [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Add-custom-HTTP-728eba24) might work for you.

Comment: I am not sure this can be executed from a remote machine can it? I do not want to copy the script to the server. I have a CI server doing deploys and would like to have it add the header when deploying. I would prefer not to have to actually copy the script to the remote machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will execute the script remotely on FILESERVER1:

```
$s = New-PsSession -ComputerName FILESERVER1
Invoke-Command -Session $s {
     .\SetHTTPResponseHeader.ps1 "Default Web Site" "Custom HTTP Header" "test"       
}
```